# Drag and Drop file upload without using file upload control in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to drag the files from desktop and drop in web application and upload files in server with out using file upload control. I need this in asp.net using Visual studio 2005. Is Drag and drop file upload process is possible in Visual studio 2005. Please urgent...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) which uses jQuery or [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) which is based on vanilla JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can try HTML5:
http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2011/09/html5-file-upload-jquery-php/

Or Jquery
http://code.google.com/p/dnd-file-upload/wiki/howto
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Comment: Thank you. But i need the drag and drop file upload process in asp.net (Visual studio 2005)

Comment: So who is stopping you to use jquery in asp.net.

Comment: We can use jquery in asp.net. But the example contains the line like $("#drop-div").dropzone({url : "http://localhost:8080/upload.php"});.  I want to upload the files in Upload folder.

Comment: Its not necessary that you can search the code that is actually as you want. You have to make changes in order to make it working according to your requirements. If you have worked with jqeury/ajax, you can really make it working for you. Otherwise this link is alien for you..